# Using l6506 with digital pot to vary force output of stepper

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I want to precisely control the amount of force being applied to a component - my plan is to drive my stepper linear actuator with the absolute minimum current to make it move, until it stalls out against my component. Then I would gradually up the current to the stepper until it was able to move another step (measuring the force being applied). I was thinking of doing this using an l6506 with a digital pot as the Rsense. Will this plan work? Many thanks!

Comment: I don't know anything about the L6506 but I suspect that Rsense is a fairly-low-value resistor.  Digital pots don't work well in that application.

Comment: How are you sensing the step transition? Stepper motors usually don't have position feedback, you would need to add a quadrature encoder or some other high-resolution mechanism. I also assume you want to put the L6506 between the driver and the h-bridge driver for the motor? What kind of current values are you expecting?

Comment: @Dwayne Reid thanks, an initial calculation suggests it needs to go as low as 1 ohm!

Comment: @Ron Beyer I wasn't thinking I needed to - it's only the force that's of interest. Perhaps I'm not understanding the difference (or similarity) of the two situations. Perhaps a servo would give more control?

Comment: @ron Beyer up to 3A I suppose - there's a few situations I need to look at with varying force requirements

Comment: A potential flaw: your stepper may stall out mid-step rather than at a step boundary when it reaches your component. Perhaps a solenoid may be an actuator to investigate?